# Why is my array returning 0 for BitRate, and ok everywhere else?

Tags: java, arrays, object, output

I'm trying to display the 10 objects in my musicLibrary array. Each object has its own Artist Name, Song Title, Bit Rate, and Total time of the song.

My run is fine everywhere except for the "BitRate = 0k" part. My run gives me BitRate = 0k for every one of the 10 objects under the Array Display. I want the BitRate for each object to be {250, 150, 350, 450, 550, 200, 100, 400, 300, 500}.
These values are all within the range I set in class iTunes. In any case, if these values weren't in the set range, I should receive an output of "Bad **_ _** input". However, what I get back is "0".

There are two separate sections in my code. 
The first part is comprised of four objects NOT in an array. To these four, I display them, mutate them, display them, set to default, then display. My run is fine here. (I didn't want to delete this portion in case of possible confusion).

The second part is my array of ten objects. For this part, I only need to display the data of the ten objects in the array. My problem is here, when I display my array and my BitRate data displays as 0.
For both parts, I am checking to see whether the values are in the range I set.

On a lesser note, can I delete my else's (marked in my code) for cleanliness' sake?

I'm confused because the code I wrote for my BitRate is essentially the same as the code I wrote for my other instance members (artist name, song title, total time), though with different variable names. I can't seem to figure out what's causing Eclipse to display "0" instead of my values. 
I'm a beginner at Java, so a simplified explanation would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Code:

```
public class Foothill {

public static void main(String [] args) {

   //default constructor 
   iTunes Coldplay = new iTunes();
   iTunes NorahJones = new iTunes();
   iTunes Banks = new iTunes();

   //constructor with parameters
   iTunes JamesBay = new iTunes("Hold Back The River", "James Bay", 300, 240006);

   //display objects immediately
   System.out.print("Initial Display: " + '\n' + '\n' );
   Coldplay.display();
   NorahJones.display();
   Banks.display();
   JamesBay.display();
   System.out.print("\n");

   //mutate many of the objects' fields
   Coldplay.setArtistName("Coldplay");
   Coldplay.setKiloBits(275);
   Coldplay.setSongTitle("Yellow");
   Coldplay.setMilliSeconds(260000);

   NorahJones.setArtistName("Norah Jones");
   NorahJones.setKiloBits(75);
   NorahJones.setSongTitle("Come Away With Me");
   NorahJones.setMilliSeconds(190000);

   Banks.setArtistName("Banks");
   Banks.setKiloBits(175);
   Banks.setSongTitle("Beggin for Thread");
   Banks.setMilliSeconds(250000);

   JamesBay.setArtistName("James Bay");
   JamesBay.setKiloBits(375);
   JamesBay.setSongTitle("Let it Go");
   JamesBay.setMilliSeconds(251000);

   //access object fields
   Coldplay.getArtistName();
   Coldplay.getSongTitle();

   NorahJones.getArtistName();
   NorahJones.getSongTitle();

   Banks.getArtistName();
   Banks.getSongTitle();

   JamesBay.getArtistName();
   JamesBay.getSongTitle();

   //check to make sure mutator call is valid
   System.out.print("Mutated Display: " + '\n' + '\n');
   if (Coldplay.setSongTitle("Viva La Vida")){ 
      Coldplay.display(); 
   }
   else { //can I delete this else?
      System.out.println("Bad Artist Name input");
   }
   if (NorahJones.setSongTitle("Come Away With Me")){
      NorahJones.display(); 
   }
   else { //can I delete this else?
      System.out.println("Bad Artist Name input");
   }
   if (Banks.setSongTitle("Beggin For Thread")){
      Banks.display();  
   } 
   else { //can I delete this else?
      System.out.println("Bad Artist Name input");
   }
   if (JamesBay.setSongTitle("Let it Go")){
      JamesBay.display(); 
      System.out.print("\n");
   }
   else { //can I delete this else?
      System.out.println("Bad Artist Name input");
   }

   //reset objects to default values
   Coldplay.setDefaults();
   NorahJones.setDefaults();
   Banks.setDefaults();
   JamesBay.setDefaults();

   //display objects for the last time
   System.out.print("Default Display: " + '\n' + '\n');
   Coldplay.display();
   NorahJones.display();
   Banks.display();
   JamesBay.display();
   System.out.println("\n");

   iTunes[] musicLibrary = new iTunes[10];
   String[] originalArtist = new String [] {"The Script", "Tegan and Sara", "Bastille", "The Beatles", "Hozier", "Sam Smith", "Birdy", "George Ezra", "Haim", "Vance Joy"};
   String[] nameArtist = new String[] {"The Script", "Tegan and Sara", "Bastille", "The Beatles", "Hozier", "Sam Smith", "Birdy", "George Ezra", "Haim", "Vance Joy"};
   String[] originalSong = new String [] {"Superheroes", "Closer", "Flaws", "Let it Be", "Take Me to Church", "Lay Me Down", "Tee Shirt", "Budapest", "Falling", "Mess Is Mine"};
   String[] titleSong = new String[] {"Superheroes", "Closer", "Flaws", "Let it Be", "Take Me to Church", "Lay Me Down", "Tee Shirt", "Budapest", "Falling", "Mess Is Mine"};
   int[] originalBit = new int [] {250, 150, 350, 450, 550, 200, 100, 400, 300, 500}; //this is should be displayed as my BitRate
   int[] rateBit = new int[] {250, 150, 350, 450, 550, 200, 100, 400, 300, 500}; //this is should be displayed as my BitRate
   int[] originalTime = new int[] {270000, 200000, 210000, 240000, 242000, 246000, 145000, 202000, 250000, 208000};
   int[] timeTotal = new int[] {270000, 200000, 210000, 240000, 242000, 246000, 145000, 202000, 250000, 208000};

   System.out.print("Array Display: " + '\n' + '\n');
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      musicLibrary[i] = new iTunes();

      if (musicLibrary[i].setArtistName(originalArtist[i])){
         musicLibrary[i].setArtistName(nameArtist[i]);
      }
      else {
         System.out.println("Bad Artist Name input");
      }
      if (musicLibrary[i].setSongTitle(originalSong[i])){
         musicLibrary[i].setSongTitle(titleSong[i]);
      }
      else {
         System.out.println("Bad Song Title input");
      }
      if (musicLibrary[i].setKiloBits(originalBit[i])){
         musicLibrary[i].setKiloBits(rateBit[i]);
      }
      else {
         System.out.println("Bad Bits Rate input");
      }
      if (musicLibrary[i].setMilliSeconds(originalTime[i])){
         musicLibrary[i].setMilliSeconds(timeTotal[i]);
      }
      else {
         System.out.println("Bad Song Length input");
      }

      musicLibrary[i].display();
   }
 }
}

class iTunes{
   //private class instance members
   private String name;
   private String artist;
   private int bitRate;
   private double totalTime;

   //public class static final constants
   public static final int MIN_BITRATE = 64;
   public static final int MAX_BITRATE = 705;
   public static final int MIN_STR_LENGTH = 1;
   public static final int MAX_STR_LENGTH = 128;
   public static final int MIN_PLAY_TIME = 5000;
   public static final int MAX_PLAY_TIME = 1000*60*60;
   public static final int DEFAULT_BITRATE = 64;
   public static final int DEFAULT_PLAY_TIME = 5000;
   public static final String DEFAULT_STRING = "(undefined)"; 

   //default constructor
   public iTunes (){
      name = "";
      artist = "";
      bitRate = 0;
      totalTime = 0;
   }
   //constructor with parameters
   iTunes (String songTitle, String artistName, int kiloBits, int milliSeconds) {
      name = songTitle;
      artist = artistName;
      bitRate = kiloBits;
      totalTime = milliSeconds;
   }
   //get/accessor and set/mutators for instance members
   public String getSongTitle() {
      return name;
   }
   public boolean setSongTitle(String songTitle) {
      if (songTitle.length() > MIN_STR_LENGTH && songTitle.length() < MAX_STR_LENGTH){
         name = songTitle;
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }
   public String getArtistName() {
      return artist;
   }
   public boolean setArtistName(String artistName) {
      if (artistName.length() > MIN_STR_LENGTH && artistName.length() < MAX_STR_LENGTH){
         artist = artistName;
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }
   public int getKiloBits() {
      return bitRate;
   }
   public boolean setKiloBits(int kiloBits) {
      if (kiloBits > MIN_BITRATE && kiloBits < MAX_BITRATE){
         bitRate = (kiloBits/1000);
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }
   public double getMilliSeconds() {
      return totalTime;
   }
   public boolean setMilliSeconds(int milliSeconds) {
      if (milliSeconds > MIN_PLAY_TIME && milliSeconds < MAX_PLAY_TIME){
         totalTime = milliSeconds;
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }
   public String timeInMinutesAndSeconds(){
      if (totalTime == 0.0){
         return (totalTime + " minutes and " + totalTime + " seconds");
      }
      else {
         int timeMinutes = (int) totalTime /60000;
         int timeRemainder = (int) totalTime - timeMinutes * 60000;
         int timeSeconds = timeRemainder/600;
         return (timeMinutes + " minutes and " + timeSeconds + " seconds");
      }
   }
   public String toString(){
      return ("Title: " + name + " / Artist: " + artist + " / Playing Time: " + timeInMinutesAndSeconds() + " / BitRate: " + bitRate + "k");  
   }
   public void setDefaults(){
      name = DEFAULT_STRING;
      artist = DEFAULT_STRING;
      bitRate = DEFAULT_BITRATE;
      totalTime = DEFAULT_PLAY_TIME;
   }
   public void display(){
      System.out.println(toString());
   }
}
```

Run:

Initial Display:

Title:  / Artist:  / Playing Time: 0.0 minutes and 0.0 seconds / BitRate: 0k

Title:  / Artist:  / Playing Time: 0.0 minutes and 0.0 seconds / BitRate: 0k

Title:  / Artist:  / Playing Time: 0.0 minutes and 0.0 seconds / BitRate: 0k

Title: Hold Back The River / Artist: James Bay / Playing Time: 4 minutes and 0 seconds / BitRate: 300k

//Assignment says to mutate only one or more members; I left BitRate = 0k here, so BitRate = 0k is expected here

Mutated Display:

Title: Viva La Vida / Artist: Coldplay / Playing Time: 4 minutes and 33 seconds / BitRate: 0k

Title: Come Away With Me / Artist: Norah Jones / Playing Time: 3 minutes and 16 seconds / BitRate: 0k

Title: Beggin For Thread / Artist: Banks / Playing Time: 4 minutes and 16 seconds / BitRate: 0k

Title: Let it Go / Artist: James Bay / Playing Time: 4 minutes and 18 seconds / BitRate: 0k

//Default BitRate = 64k here, is as expected

Default Display:

Title: (undefined) / Artist: (undefined) / Playing Time: 0 minutes and 8 seconds / BitRate: 64k

Title: (undefined) / Artist: (undefined) / Playing Time: 0 minutes and 8 seconds / BitRate: 64k

Title: (undefined) / Artist: (undefined) / Playing Time: 0 minutes and 8 seconds / BitRate: 64k

Title: (undefined) / Artist: (undefined) / Playing Time: 0 minutes and 8 seconds / BitRate: 64k

//My problem occurs in Array Display: all my BitRates = 0k

Array Display:

Title: Superheroes / Artist: The Script / Playing Time: 4 minutes and 50 seconds / BitRate: 0k

Title: Closer / Artist: Tegan and Sara / Playing Time: 3 minutes and 33 seconds / BitRate: 0k

Title: Flaws / Artist: Bastille / Playing Time: 3 minutes and 50 seconds / BitRate: 0k

Title: Let it Be / Artist: The Beatles / Playing Time: 4 minutes and 0 seconds / BitRate: 0k

Title: Take Me to Church / Artist: Hozier / Playing Time: 4 minutes and 3 seconds / BitRate: 0k

Title: Lay Me Down / Artist: Sam Smith / Playing Time: 4 minutes and 10 seconds / BitRate: 0k

Title: Tee Shirt / Artist: Birdy / Playing Time: 2 minutes and 41 seconds / BitRate: 0k

Title: Budapest / Artist: George Ezra / Playing Time: 3 minutes and 36 seconds / BitRate: 0k

Title: Falling / Artist: Haim / Playing Time: 4 minutes and 16 seconds / BitRate: 0k

Title: Mess Is Mine / Artist: Vance Joy / Playing Time: 3 minutes and 46 seconds / BitRate: 0k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is :

bitRate = (kiloBits/1000)

This is doing integer division which is giving you your answer of 0.

You should probably be declaring bitRate as a double and then doing:

bitRate = (kiloBits/1000.00) .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your setKiloBits method:

```
public boolean setKiloBits(int kiloBits) {
      if (kiloBits > MIN_BITRATE && kiloBits < MAX_BITRATE){
         bitRate = (kiloBits/1000);
         return true;
      }
      return false;
}
```

You divide an int by an int, and as the result is less than 1 (320/1000 = .32 etc) it truncates the remainder. Try this:

```
public boolean setKiloBits(int kiloBits) {
      if (kiloBits > MIN_BITRATE && kiloBits < MAX_BITRATE){
         bitRate = (kiloBits/1000.0);
         return true;
      }
      return false;
}
```

However, as you are converting from kilobit to bit, I think you actually meant to multiply by 1000? But thats up to you on the business logic.

Edit: As Alpertmd pointed out, you'd also need to change the definition of bitrate to double if you wished to divide.